# Fetching Nested BelongsToMany Association

Tags: javascript, orm, sequelize.js, model-associations

So I have `Projects` which have `Investigators` in `Roles` and commit `Effort` as a `Role` in a `BudgetPeriod` (sounds stupidly complicated doesn't it). I have no idea what keywords are actually appropriate to even search for this. so here goes:

```
const Project = seq.define('Project', {/*...*/});
const Investigator = seq.define('Investigator', {/*...*/});
const BudgetPeriod = seq.define('BudgetPeriod', {/*...*/});
const Role = seq.define('Role', {
  id:           {
    type:          DataTypes.INTEGER,
    primaryKey:    true,
    autoIncrement: true
  },
  role:         {
    type:      DataTypes.ENUM,
    /*...*/
  },
  /*... Other role related info...*/
});
const Effort = seq.define('Effort', {
  id:           {
    type:          DataTypes.INTEGER,
    primaryKey:    true,
    autoIncrement: true
  },
  budgetedAY: {
    type:         DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull:    false,
    defaultValue: 0
  },
  /*... other effort related info...*/
});
```

Okay, now the relations:

```
// Each Project can have many budget periods, BP knows its Project
Project.hasMany(BudgetPeriod, {as: 'budgetPeriods'});

// Each Project has many Investigators, which have a Role on Many projects
Project.belongsToMany(Investigator, {as: 'investigators', through: db.Role});

// Each Investigator, in their role, commits Effort toward the Projects during a BudgetPeriod
Role.belongsToMany(BudgetPeriod, {as: 'effort', through: db.Effort});
```

In my query I am getting a Project and fetching its associated BudgetPeriods and Investigators/Roles. **I don't know how to get Effort because it is associated with the relational model `Roles` not Investigator and `Role` is not directly associated with `Project` according to sequelize.**

```
Project.findById(projectId, {
  include: [
    {model: Investigator, as: 'investigators'},
    {model: BudgetPeriod, as: 'budgetPeriods'},
  ],
  order:   [
    [{model: BudgetPeriod, as: 'budgetPeriods'}, 'period', 'ASC']
  ]
}).then(res => console.log(res))

// Produces something like
{
  budgetPeriods: [/*...*/],
  investigators: [
    {
      id:1, 
      name:'abc', 
      Role: {
        id: 1,
        role: 'PI'
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I don't know how to get Effort in this query. I tried changing `{model: Investigator, as: 'investigators'},` to `{model: Investigator, as: 'investigators', include: [{model: Effort, as: 'effort'}]},` and other variations. I also tried putting `{model: BudgetPeriod, as: 'effort'}` and other variations on the root `include`, but I these all result in messages like `BudgetPeriod (effort) is not associated to Investigator!`

The reason this is so odd is because I have to associate a model to a relational model through another relational model.

Thank you for any help you might be able to offer!

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't think there will be an answer to this, I refactored the database relations. For those who have issues similar, here is my change.

Database Definitions: No Change

Database Relations:

```
Project.hasMany(BudgetPeriod, {as: 'budgetPeriods'});
Project.belongsToMany(Investigator, {as: 'investigators', through: db.Role});
Investigator.belongsToMany(BudgetPeriod, {as: 'effort', through: db.Effort});
```

Since each Investigator may only have ONE Role in each Project, it is safe to assume that each effort committed by an Investigator in a BudgetPeriod is done so by that Role.

This changes my query to

```
Project.findById(projectId, {
  include: [
    {model: Investigator, as: 'investigators',
      include: [{model: BudgetPeriod, as: 'effort', where: {ProjectId: projectId}}]},
    {model: BudgetPeriod, as: 'budgetPeriods'},
  ],
  order:   [
    [{model: BudgetPeriod, as: 'budgetPeriods'}, 'period', 'ASC']
  ]
}).then(res => console.log(res))

// Produces something like
{
  budgetPeriods: [/*...*/],
  investigators: [
    {
      id:1, 
      name:'abc', 
      Role: {
        id: 1,
        role: 'PI'
      },
      Effort: [
        /* ... Effort ... */
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```